# How can I render a fire and smoke simulation in Cycles with alpha channel?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, transparency, smoke-simulation

How can I render a fire and smoke simulation in the Cycles render, with alpha channel for further compositing?

Comment: There is a very nice tutorial about working a sandstorm with smoke simulation here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzgrK3mnq9o

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32900/how-to-properly-render-smoke-on-a-transparent-background and this - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles