# Can you render a PNG animation with smoke and a transparent background?

Tags: rendering, animation, transparency, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to make a title animation with smoke simulations and I want to overlay it on video in after effects. Can I render it with transparency or is there an alternative?
Blender 2.78
Computer specs: good enough

Comment: PNG is not the best format for this. read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32900/how-to-properly-render-smoke-on-a-transparent-background and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50607/transparent-background-for-volumetric-smoke-bug/50892#50892

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can render to .png as an image sequence - the first part is already set as default for you in the output panel. The next step is to change form 'sky' to 'transparent' if you are in blender render, and if in Cycles you need to set 'transparent' under the Film tab.[image: sky vs transparent][image: Cycles transparent]

Comment: I don't seem to have the shading drop-down menu.

Comment: Shading dropdown is in the Render tab of the Properties Editor in Blender Render - if in Cycles, you should look for the Film tab and check the box to enable transparent.

Answer (score 1):

The earlier provided answer is correct, however there is another (faster, less resource intensive) way.

If your smoke is non-emissive (i.e. there is no fire that is to illuminate other geometry) and shading is not an issue, I would suggest OpenGL rendering the smoke from the viewport as its much much faster. The setting stay as specified in the other answer and you put out a PNG sequence.

Just turn on high resolution smoke to be visible in viewport and change the viewport display to "render only". The quality will be decent, however you sacrifice the shading.

For simple mist, smoke or fog this is a great timesaver and generates better results than AE plugins like particular.

[image]