# Need help saving an png with an alpha map

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I want render an image with a flame in cycles using volumetrics but the problem is whenever I am trying to save the image it save the image completely white(i.e. only an alpha map and no image). It doesn't happen with any other non-alpha formats like jpeg.

If anyone can figure out what the problem is then it would be a great help

Blend File:-https://pasteall.org/blend/ddcfc5cf25c441eba5832d68323f2ee3

Comment: This is just a work around using Gimp untill someone comes up with a how to do it in Blender. In Blender, Render Properties > Film > uncheck the Transparent option. Now the background is Black in render view. Render and Save as png image with the RGBA option selected.  Open image in Gimp then, Layer > Transparency > Color to Alpha > change colour to Black and then OK the Color to Alpha. You now have the transparent background for your flame.

Comment: Related questions: [transparent background for volumetric smoke? Bug?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/50607/107598) and (linked in the first one) [How to properly render smoke on a transparent background?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32900/107598)