# Why does rendered fire on transparent background look different than on preview?

Tags: rendering

Why does rendered fire on transparent background look different than on preview?

Preview:

[image: preview]

Render with transparent background:

[image: rendered transparent background]

It seems that the flame loses its  red color in my final render,

But it's weird that it appeared normal when I use a non-transparent background.

With background: 
[image: with background]

This are my nodes settings: 
[image: nodes]

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your file, but blender's render view has a problem dislpaying it. Displaying emissions that are also transparent (like fire or glare) doesn't work. The good news is that you composite them into a background correctly Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32900/how-to-properly-render-smoke-on-a-transparent-background and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824

Answer (score 0):

To closely match viewport and final render you have to give both the same render settings...which ends up for you waiting for the viewport rendering the same time as for the final render.
Second thing: The human optical perception can easily be tricked into "seeing" something, which isn't there or looks different, which is identical. Example:
[Totally different greys are identical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checker_shadow_illusion)
If it doesn't came out totally different (for example a red rose turns blue) it is the result of subtle differences in the render settings playing games with your optical persception. So far the theoretical part of it. :)

If the alpha channel has a greater influence of the results, check the setting of the viewport regarding transperancy and the handling of the alpha channel.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer and i also think the problem may lie in alpha. But i have no idea on it ╮（╯＿╰）╭ I tried to alpha over it,and it works, which means the invisible color/objects in the previous pictures can be seen right now. However, the final render's background turned black but not a transparent one. Totally got no clues of it...