# Fire not showing up when I make the background transparent

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency, fire

I cant figure out why the fire disappears when I switch to a transparent background with cycles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use the search box at the top to look for previously asked questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=fire+transparent+cycles

Comment: Your image is fine, but the render window cannot display it . It is an old bug in the viewer  read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44222/92768 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824 on top of that, if you save the image as PNG the information is lost. Use a format like EXR or composite directly on blender.