# Compositing - Glare Effect/Node in Viewport different than Render

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, glare

When I try to use the glare in the compositing editor, the live viewport as well as single frames will render showing these RGB reflections/glare that I want.

The problem is, when I save the photo, the RGB reflections/glares disappear. How do I save and keep this effect the same as what the viewport shows me?

[image: BlenderGlare_Viewport Showing Desired Effect]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the effect to save when I save the renders as .EXR filetype. Weirdly, when importing the .EXR into premier pro, the effect is lost again. However when I import it into Da Vinci Resolve, it works.

Comment: yes it's a problem of alpha transparency, it removes the effect, there are some tricks to fix that though

Comment: How do you go about fixing that? The EXR thing I did will only work for animations - single frame renders still don't give me the same image as the viewport.

Comment: I haven't tried any of these solutions but maybe check this page: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32900/how-to-properly-render-smoke-on-a-transparent-background or this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=tmb5HRU1cUo